# How to add TEXT from a DIV tag into a LINK in my code with jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, hyperlink, replace, href

I currently have a receipt that is being written by asp which I cannot control.  I want to copy the invoice with jquery and then input in into a link.  I have a very basic understanding of jquery and know this can be done, but not sure where to start.

```
<div id="orderid">34332</div>
<a href="http://mysite.com/order/------.html"></a>
```

I need to be able to replace the ------ with the order id.

I know I can turn the order id into a variable as there is an id attached to the div tag, but am totally lost on how to input it into the href

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following if there is always an anchor tag following the div.

```
$('#orderid').next('a').attr('href', 'http://mysite.com/order/' + $('#orderid').html() + '.html');
```

Or probably a little less obtrusive:

```
$('#orderid').next('a').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://mysite.com/order/' + $('#orderid').html() + '.html');
});
```